# Setting Expires cache in webapplication for JBoss application server not working right

Tags: jsf, caching, filter

I have set up a cache-filter for my web application in JBoss Application Server 7.1.1

by using the setHeader and setDateHeader functions of the response.

The Expires date is always set to 1 month in the future since
the server has been restarted - The month is also depending on the current month:
So if the server has been restarted on e.g.:

Wed, 21 Mar 2018 10:34 GMT 
i will set the expire date to:

Wed, 21 **Apr** 2018 10:34 GMT or depending on the current date:

But in the Google-Chrome-Tools i will always see a wrong Expires-Date:

**e.g. theme.css :**

- Status        : 200
- Type          : stylesheet
- Cache-Control : public, must-revalidate ***(This is as i set in my filter)***
- Expires       : Wed, 28 Mar 2018 12:04:30 GMT ***(This is wrong)***

instead of using my Expires-Date which i have sent:

- Expires       : Wed, 21 Apr 2018 10:34 GMT

I don't know where the problem is and i am using currently this functions in my filter:

```
@Override
public void doFilter(ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response, FilterChain chain)
        throws IOException, ServletException
{
    // Get request datas:
    HttpServletResponse httpResponse = (HttpServletResponse)response;
    HttpServletRequest reqt = (HttpServletRequest) request;
    // Ignore ajax-request's:
    String reqURI       = reqt.getRequestURI().toLowerCase().trim();
    String reqURIContext    = reqt.getContextPath().toLowerCase()+ '/';
    String reqURIPart = reqURI.substring(reqURIContext.trim().length()).toLowerCase().trim();
    String CACHE_MEDIA  =       ";.js;.css;.svg;.png;.jpg;.gif;.pdf;.ico;.woff2;.woff;.ttf;.otf;.eot;"
                                                +ResourceHandler.RESOURCE_IDENTIFIER+";";

            Boolean useCache = false;
            // Set Browser cache for all resources including all media files :
            String[] medias2cache = CACHE_MEDIA.split(";");
            for (int idx=1;idx<medias2cache.length;idx++)
            {
                if (reqURI.contains(medias2cache[idx]))
                {
                    useCache = true;
                    break;
                }
            }
            // Set browser-cache:
            if (useCache)
            {
                httpResponse.setHeader("Cache-Control", "public, must-revalidate");
                httpResponse.setDateHeader("Expires", InitBean.getStartupDateTime4CacheAsTimeStamp());
                logger.info("*** Setting cache for static resource '"+reqURIPart+ '\'');
            }
            else
            {
                httpResponse.setHeader("Cache-Control", "no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate"); // HTTP 1.1.
                httpResponse.setHeader("Pragma", "no-cache"); // HTTP 1.0.
                httpResponse.setDateHeader("Expires", 0); // Proxies.
                logger.info("*** No cache for '"+reqURIPart+ '\'');
            }
    // Continue with next filter:
    chain.doFilter(request, response);
}
```

and the InitBean-Part which is called on each startup of the Server:

```
@Singleton
@Startup
    public class InitBean 
    {
        // Time on which server has been restarted:
        private static Date startUpDateTime = new Date();
        @PostConstruct
        private void StartUp() 
        {
            // Set startup date/time
            InitBean.startUpDateTime = new Date(System.currentTimeMillis());
        }
        public static Long getStartupDateTime4CacheAsTimeStamp()
        {
            // Calculate date difference in month since server has been started up:
            Calendar startCalendar = new GregorianCalendar();
            startCalendar.setTime(startUpDateTime);
            Calendar endCalendar = new GregorianCalendar();
            endCalendar.setTime(new Date());
            //
            int diffYear = endCalendar.get(Calendar.YEAR) - startCalendar.get(Calendar.YEAR);
            int diffMonth = diffYear * 12 + endCalendar.get(Calendar.MONTH) - startCalendar.get(Calendar.MONTH);
            // And set expiration date to 1 month in the future from server startup :
            diffMonth++;
            // Get date in future:
            startCalendar.add(Calendar.MONTH, diffMonth);
            return startCalendar.getTimeInMillis();
        }
    }
```